# Como animar diferentes semicirculos

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

estoy tratando de graficar en este caso 2 semicirculos, primero quiero que el primer radio del semicirculo vaya incrementando en funcion del tiempo, despues de un tiempo estimado quiero que otro semicirculo se genere y que tambien su radio vaya incrementando en funcion del tiempo.

Este es el codigo

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


x1=[]
x2=[]
x3=[]
x4=[]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x1, x2)
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.set_xlim(-30,30)
ax.set_ylim(0,32)
line, = ax.plot(0,0)
line2, = ax.plot(0,0)

def animacion(i):
      theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
      x1 = i*np.cos(theta/2)
      x2 = i*np.sin(theta/2)
      line.set_xdata(x1)
      line.set_ydata(x2)
      return line,

def animacion2(i):
      theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
      x3 = i*np.cos(theta/2)
      x4 = i*np.sin(theta/2)
      line.set_xdata(x3)
      line.set_ydata(x4)
      return line2,


animation= FuncAnimation(fig, func=animacion , frames= np.arange(0,30, 0.01), interval = 1)
animation2 = FuncAnimation(fig2, func=animacion2, frames= np.arange(0,30,0.01), interval = 3)
plt.show()
```

Agregue otra formula para que se creara el otro semicirculo, sin embargo al momento de correr el programa solo crea un semicirculo y  cambia el radio entre las dos funciones declaradas.

Comment: Creas dos figuras pero solo usas el eje de una.... ¿Quieres mostrar cada semicirculo en una ventana distinta o ambos en la misma? ¿si es en la misma las quieres en el mismo gráfico (eje) o cada una en un eje distinto?

Comment: Las quiero mostrar los semi-circulos en la misma ventana o grafica, y sobre el mismo eje

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta que la función puede retornar múltiples artists a actualizar. El problema sería el delay entre cada semicírculo,una idea sería valerte del argumento `i` para solo empezar a actualizar cada linea cuando se haya elcanzado cierto valor de `i`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.set_xlim(-30, 30)
ax.set_ylim(0, 32)

lines = [ax.plot(0, 0)[0] for _ in range(5)]
start_times = (0, 2, 3, 5, 7)


def animacion(i):
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    for line, start_time in zip(lines, start_times):
        if start_time <= i:
            x1 = (i - start_time) * np.cos(theta / 2)
            x2 = (i - start_time) * np.sin(theta / 2)
            line.set_xdata(x1)
            line.set_ydata(x2)
    return lines


animation = FuncAnimation(
    fig, func=animacion, frames=np.arange(0, 30, 0.01), interval=1
    )
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que cuando se cumpla un ciclo los que aún no han alcanzado el radio máximo sigan expandiéndose, si no te importa que en el primer ciclo todos tengan radio 0 de inicio, puedes hacer simplemente:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.set_xlim(-30, 30)
ax.set_ylim(0, 32)

start_times = [0, 7, 13]
lines = [ax.plot(0, 0)[0] for _ in range(len(start_times))]

def animacion(i):
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    for line, start_time in zip(lines, start_times):
        t = (start_time + i) % 30 
        x1 = t * np.cos(theta / 2)
        x2 = t * np.sin(theta / 2)
        line.set_xdata(x1)
        line.set_ydata(x2)
    return lines


animation = FuncAnimation(
    fig, func=animacion, frames=np.arange(0, 30, 0.01), interval=1
    )
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, en si eso era lo que queria poder manipular el tiempo de cada uno de los semicirculos, sin embargo, quiero que la linea azul desaparezaca al momento de llegar a radio 30 pero que las otras lineas sigan expandiendose hasta que cada una cumpla con un radio de 30. No se si seria con un ciclo for o if booleano para poder cmplir la condición que anteriormente mencionaba,